# Vaadin 23 change text color for TextField component

Tags: vaadin, textfield, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

In case of error, I need to change the text of `TextField` to var(--lumo-error-text-color)

I tried the following:

```
textField.getStyle().set("color", "var(--lumo-error-text-color)");
```

but it doesn't work. How to properly change the text color of TextField component?

Answer (score 3):

That does work just fine for me. However, assuming you want *all* TextFields to have red text when they're invalid, that really would be more appropriate to handle in CSS: Just add the following block to your styles.css:

```
vaadin-text-field[invalid]::part(input-field) {
  color: var(--lumo-error-text-color);
}
```

Or, if you want that across *all* text input fields, skip the element name:

```
[invalid]::part(input-field) {
  color: var(--lumo-error-text-color);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately this is not related to the validation aspect. I just need to be able to do this on demand on a concrete fields (not all)

Comment: How to add this style inline to the component?

Comment: Well, like mentioned above your code does work just fine for me. But, as Henry below suggests, you could also apply a css classname (e.g. "my-invalid") to the textfield and write the css as:

vaadin-text-field.my-invalid::part(input-field) {
  color: var(--lumo-error-text-color);
}

Answer (score 0):

Since the text field is slotted, I don't believe you can set it's color property inline.  You can add/remove a class name and use the method suggested above. Just have one class set the text to error color and the other class set it back to the regular color.